# Fast solution (DB) for flexible search at big data

Tags: database, search

I need a fast (less than 30 seconds response) solution (DB) for:

- search by different several fields;
- order the results by different columns;
- and tables may contains about 10 billions rows.
- duration less than 30 seconds response;

Could you share your experience please?

Tried ClickHouse but it's has timeouts when we order by not PK columns